# What is the purpose of the DEPLOYMENT qmake variable?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake

I am trying to get to the next level of understanding of the Qt library and *qmake* in particular. For that purpose I experiment with diffrent project configurations. Doing that I've stumbled upon the *DEPLOYMENT* variable (because of the autocomplete), which is not listed in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) of qmake. The search engines don't give me suitable results either. I am pretty sure there is a reason for that, but being a scientist I am used to not leaving a stone unturned. So it does bother me and I would like to find out what it is for. Is anyone familiar with this variable?

Comment: Can it be just QMAKE_IOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET or QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET?

Comment: @demonplus It’s exactly DEPLOYMENT and according to the answer it’s not relevant in Qt5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DEPLOYMENT`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#deployment) is used in Qt 4.8 to specify additional files to be deployed on Windows CE and the Symbian platform only:

> *This is only used on Windows CE and the Symbian platform.*
>
> Specifies which additional files will be deployed. Deployment means
>   the transfer of files from the development system to the target device
>   or emulator.

Comment: Great! That is what I was looking for. Thank you!